# Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded)

Tags: cassandra

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 0 replica responded); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only

I am getting the above error for while executing a query on one of the Cassandra table of my application? The table has 3 columns promo ,store and upc. promo is the type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED & both store and upc are type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED. I am getting this for only one of the promo. How can I resolve this?

Comment: How many nodes in your cluster? Can you please run nodetool describecluster on all nodes and check whether any schema mismatch. Also you can check all node status from nodetool status command.

Comment: Run `nodetool tablehistograms` on your keyspace.table.  I'm curious as to how large your partitions are.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the nodes in your cluster were unresponsive. You need to investigate why. Start by reviewing the `system.log` and `debug.log` on the nodes.

In a lot of cases, this is caused by nodes being overloaded and GC pauses. Cheers!